# PeerConnection creating incomplete offer

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp

I am trying to create offer but I get incomplete `sdp-offer` like below

```
sdp:
"v=0↵o=- 981077471509521330 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS
↵"
```

What am I missing out. My code is as follows

//The adapter part

```
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || 
window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
window.RTCIceCandidate = window.RTCIceCandidate ||     
window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.webkitRTCIceCandidate;
window.RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription ||    
window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;
window.URL = window.URL || window.mozURL || window.webkitURL;
window.navigator.getUserMedia = window.navigator.getUserMedia ||      
window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

Creating sdp flow

```
var iceConfig = {'iceServers': [{ 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }]};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
pc.onicecandidate = function (evnt) {
socket.emit('video', {ice: evnt.candidate, type: 'ice' });
  };
pc.onaddstream = function(evnt) {
 $rootScope.remotestream = evnt.stream;
 $rootScope.$broadcast('remotestream');
};
pc.createOffer(function(offer) {console.log(offer);});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things I spotted:

- you need to add a local stream to RTCPeerConnection: `pc.addStream(localStream);`, localStream is usually the one obtained with `navigator.getUserMedia()`
- you need to pass `iceConfig` as the first parameter to RTCPeerConnection constructor

For more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection, especially *Initializing a call* section.